# Can SAS macro variables created in remote session be used in local program submission

Tags: sas

Could any one help me  in providing any solution to my issue explained below?

I am running some part of the code in SAS which is submitted in remote server. and then I have to export the the created dataset to excel. 
so i wrote a export code outside remote submission, but it is not able to use the parameters defined in remote session.

Please provide any work around for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're using `RSUBMIT`, i.e. SAS/CONNECT, right?  Always helpful to have a short example of code to make that sort of thing clear.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your parameters back to the local session as follows:

```
rsubmit;
  %put NOTE: running remotely;
  %let myvar=&syscp;
  %sysrput localvar=&myvar;
endrsubmit;

%put &=localvar;
```

Remember that your excel export process will need to read your remote data so be sure to use the right library (eg RWORK).

Comment: also useful is `%SYSLPUT` of course (documented [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/connref/67933/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1bc4zi0lp02ivn1oxn9gc1bsaha.htm))